# How to change Rails 3.0's default log path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-3

I have to change my rail application's default log path because of my company's internal software deployment process: basically my rails app ends up on a read-only location, and I need the log files written in a directory "made for this".

With Rails 2.x we used to add some black magic in our FCGI script to force that in when deployed on prod. hosts:

```
class Rails::Configuration
   def default_log_path
     File.join(ENV['SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VAR'], "var/output/logs/rails.log")
   end
 end
```

However, Configuration isn't a class anymore in Rails 2.3 (it's a module), and it appears to me there isn't any default_log_path involved there anymore as well...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need define your logger

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(File.join(ENV['SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VAR'], "var/output/logs/rails.log"))
```

This trick works with Rails 2 too. And you can define by environment where you really want your log file.

Comment: Actually Rails3 (at least) has a config.log_path which I used and worked perfectly. But I wouldn't have found without your (actually very sensible) solution :)

Comment: like you want. You can change your logger with the config.logger configuration too. Use Syslogger by example. Put your found on answer. It's more better.

Comment: Actually, is there a canonical source of information on these configuration properties? I haven't found one comprehensive one so far...

Comment: I don't really found too. But I think you can ask in SO Question :)

Comment: config.log_path doesn't do anything at all for me in Rails 3.1. config.logger does, however.

Comment: As per Rails official documentation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) this is the proper way to do this.

Comment: In Rails 4 this should be `config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(File.join(ENV['SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VAR'], "var/output/logs/rails.log"))` (it seems BufferedLogger has been removed).

Answer (score 9):

The `config.log_path` setting has been deprecated - the recommended solution is now:

`config.paths.log = "/some/path/#{Rails.env}.log"`

Comment: This syntax doesn't appear correct. In the config block, if you do a `config.paths['logfile'] = '...'` that seems right but LogTailer still complains.

Comment: For me, `config.paths['log']` like suggested by @aceofspades (below, not `logfile`) worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

As of Rails 3.2.3, looks like the log pathname is also defined in `Rails::Rack::LogTailer#initialize`, and that comes from Rails::Server#log_path.

```
LOG_PATH = "log/mylog.log"

require 'rails/commands/server'
module Rails
  class Server
    def log_path
      LOG_PATH
    end
  end
end

class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  config.paths['log'] = LOG_PATH
  ...
end
```