# How to create a log folder before rails application loads the config.logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, jruby, warbler

1. I have an rails app. I am using Jruby/Warble/Jetty to create the executable war file. Copy paste the war file into a separate folder.
2. I want the application to log outside the war file. So i am using the solution from this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943444/how-to-change-rails-3-0s-default-log-path)

3.

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(File.join(ENV['RAILS_ENV'], "#{Rails.root}/logs/#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}.log"))
```

3. When the rails server boots up. It says "Automatic creation of logging directories has been deprecated in rails". [SEE Kevin Bedell Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096219/how-to-create-a-folder-if-not-present-with-logger-new)

How do I create a folder when the rails application starts so that the folder is created when the application boots up and the logs can access the created folder.

Where should I add the code in which folder under \config so that it loads the code which creates a directory first and then uses the config? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy Paste it config/environments/development.rb

```
log_file_name = "#{Rails.root}/logs/#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}.log"
unless File.exist?(File.dirname(log_file_name))
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(log_file_name))
  File.new(log_file_name, 'a+')
end

config.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(File.join("#{Rails.root}", "logs", "#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}.log"))
```

For 'a+' in File.new see this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631633/ruby-why-cant-i-create-a-new-file)

You can also use the config/application.rb [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557850/how-do-i-have-different-envirenment-variable-values-in-rails)